# Pex reuses values

Tags: c#, moles, pex, pex-and-moles

I am using Pex to generate test cases.
I have a function that looks similar to the one below:

```
public void function(List<string> list, List<List<string>> listOfLists){
    // do something with the lists (add values, remove them, ...)
}
```

However, I recently noticed that sometimes Pex creates test cases where `list` is one of the values in `listOfLists`. This behaviour is not possible in my function and I would like to suppress this generation. 
Is there a way to prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 0):

Please use PexAssume (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.pex.framework.pexassume.aspx) to express any such assumptions or preconditions on the inputs that IntelliTest generates.